# Not able to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, osx-lion, rubymine

Any suggestions on why am I getting this? My ruby version is `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11.1.0]` and rails version is `Rails 3.1.1`. I have done `bundle install` and `gem update --system`.

```
➜  expertiza git:(master) ✗ rails server   
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/vsingh3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this same problem a while back and I think it was due to an outdated gemfile. Make sure you have the same version of rails listed in your gemfile as is installed on your machine.

Comment: Oh I see. In Gemfile of my project the rails version is 'rails', '~> 2.3.14', whereas I have Rails 3.1.1 installed on my computer. What is preferable i.e changing the rails version on my Gemfile or downgrading rails on my computer?

Comment: If this is a new project then just change the Gemfile. No reason not to use the latest and greatest. If the project was developed in 2.3.14 then you will probably encounter some problems trying to run it under rails 3. Might be worth it though, Rails has come a long way since then.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) if you don't currently.  It will keep all of your environments for different applications separate (including ruby versions and gem lists/versions).